# Cannot access memory at address 0x ffffdfc4

Tags: linux, assembly

I have assembly language progamme，but it show error

> “Program received signal SIGSEGV，Segentation fault”

Why？the program is below:

```
.code32
.section .data

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
pushl $3   
pushl $2 

call power
addl $8, %esp
pushl %eax

pushl $2
pushl $5
call power
addl $8, %esp
popl %ebx

addl %eax, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80

.type power,@function
power:
pushl %ebp 
movl %esp, %ebp 
subl $4, %esp 
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
movl %ebx, -4(%ebp)

power_loop_start:
cmpl $1, %ecx 
je power_loop_end

movl -4(%ebp), %eax
imull %ebx, %eax
movl %eax, -4(%ebp)
decl %ecx 
jmp power_loop_start

power_loop_end:
movl -4(%ebp), %eax
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

After compilation to run the program,it show segmentation fault (core dump) and gdb says:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV,Segregation fault.
```

Why and how I fix it?

Comment: In power eax is not used for anything else, so you can replace "movl %ebx, -4(%ebp)" with "movl %ebx, %eax" and remove all other instructions containing -4(%ebp).

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450325/memory-access-error-0xffffdfc4)

Comment: Your problem might be, that you compile to 64 in stead of 32 bit. If that is the case you need to give the right compiler option.

Comment: @MikkelChristiansen how to give the right compiler option

Comment: @shengfu zou `--32` does it for GNU as.

Comment: @cad oh，thanks，I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is that I use 64 to compile 32 bit program.And I add some compiler

options to solve it.Such as bellow:

as -32 power.s -o power.o

ld -m elf_i386 power.o -o power

./power